# Shared lifecycle cross processes with boost::interprocess::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-interprocess

I'm trying to use the boost::interprocess in order to share data between processes and utilize the shared_ptr for lifecycle management. I have a map residing in the shared memory and two processes should access it.

```
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file> segment =
          boost::make_shared<boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file>
                 (boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
                  "./some-mmap.txt", //file name
                  65536);           //segment size in bytes

    pair_allocator_type alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());

    elements = boost::interprocess::make_managed_shared_ptr(
            segment->find_or_construct<map_type>("elements")
            (std::less<IdType>(), alloc_inst),
            *segment
    );
```

In a test program I have, a Parent and a Child process which essentially both use the piece of code from above. Therefore, they use the same underlying file, same name of the shared object ("elements"), same types, etc.

However, I noticed that whenever a child process dies, the size of the collection dropped to 0. Strange. I investigated and it seemed that it had to do with the destruction of `elements` (when this shared pointer goes out of scope). Whenever `elements` went out of scope, the size of the underlying collection went to 0.

I also saw that the `elements` has the `use_count` **exactly 1** in both Parent and Child process. For Parent that makes sense, but I don't get it why is it the case for Child. My assumption is that when the Child process dies, the use_count drops to 0, and then the collection is cleared.

What I want is that the pointed object (map) is not destroyed when the Child process dies. I should not make assumptions which processes are active and which ones not.

- Am I initializing the `boost::interprocess::shared_ptr` in a wrong way?
- Am I missing completely the semantics of this pointer --> is it used only to manage shared-memory objects lifecycle **only** within one process and not across processes?
- How to have a shared_ptr whose use_count is shared across processes?

**EDIT - clarifications on collection**

The `elements` is a `boost::interprocess::map` that maps a certain `IdType` to a shared-memory shared pointer to `ShmemType`. The size of `elements` drops to 0 when the Child process dies.

```
typedef boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager segment_manager_type;
typedef std::pair<const IdType, ShmemType::pointer_type> pair_type;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<pair_type, segment_manager_type> pair_allocator_type;
typedef boost::interprocess::map<IdType, ShmemType::pointer_type, std::less<IdType>, pair_allocator_type> map_type;
```

**EDIT - example from boost docs**

I've taken the examples from boost docs and expanded on it to track down the root cause of my original problem.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system

using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<int, managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

#include <iostream>

//Main function. For parent process argc == 1, for child process argc == 2
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(argc == 1){ //Parent process

      //Create a new segment with given name and size
       managed_mapped_file segment(open_or_create, "./a_MySharedMemory.txt", 65536);

      //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
      const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

//      MyVector* elements = segment.find_or_construct<MyVector>("some-vector")      //object name
//                      (alloc_inst);
       typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_ptr<MyVector, boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file>::type map_pointer_type;

        map_pointer_type elements = boost::interprocess::make_managed_shared_ptr(
                segment.find_or_construct<MyVector>("some-vector")      //object name
                (alloc_inst),
                segment
        );

      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)  //Insert data in the vector
          elements->push_back(i);

      std::cout << elements->size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << elements->at(0) << std::endl;
        std::cout << elements->at(30) << std::endl;

      //Launch child process
      std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
      if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
         return 1;

      std::cout << elements->size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << elements->at(0) << std::endl;
      std::cout << elements->at(30) << std::endl;

   }
   else{ //Child process
      //Open the managed segment
       managed_mapped_file segment(open_only, "./a_MySharedMemory.txt");
       const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

       typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_ptr<MyVector, boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file>::type map_pointer_type;

       map_pointer_type elements = boost::interprocess::make_managed_shared_ptr(
            segment.find_or_construct<MyVector>("some-vector")      //object name
            (alloc_inst),
            segment
    );

//       MyVector* elements = segment.find_or_construct<MyVector>("some-vector")      //object name
//                      (alloc_inst);

      //Use vector in reverse order
      std::sort(elements->rbegin(), elements->rend());

   }

   return 0;
}
```

In this case the vector has size == 0 in the parent process after the child process dies. If I use the raw pointer (`MyVector* elements = segment.find_or_construct...`), then the collection can be used as expected in the parent process.

So I still have my doubts about the behavior of the shared pointer

Comment: "size of the collection dropped to 0" - which collection?

Comment: I clarified in the text. The `elements->size()` gives 0 in the parent process after the child process dies, even though `elements` map is not modified in the child process.

Comment: And before the child process dies?

Comment: It's one. 

Test that I made is parent adds one element, spawns a child process, child reads this one element, child process dies, parent reads that one element. Last read should succeed, but it fails (there's nothing in the `elements` map).

Comment: The size dropping to 0 makes no sense. That's not what smart pointers do, not without a custom deleter anyways. You should check that the map is actually the same object (and it still exists!). Did you keep the segment alive long enough? (Make the segment global for testing, e.g.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The issue was related to how the shared pointers are made

If you call `boost::interprocess::make_managed_shared_ptr` N times to created a shared pointer to an object in shared memory, you get essentially different (completely unrelated) shared pointers to the **same** object in the shared memory. I was doing that in the Parent and the Child process, and then when the Child process died, the use count went to 0 and erased the pointed object (the map).

The solution was to create a named shared pointer explicitly.

```
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<void, segment_manager_type>  void_allocator_type;
typedef boost::interprocess::deleter<map_type, segment_manager_type>  map_deleter_type;
typedef boost::interprocess::shared_ptr<map_type, void_allocator_type, map_deleter_type> map_pointer_type;

segment_manager_type* segment_manager = segment->get_segment_manager();
pair_allocator_type alloc_inst(segment_manager);

segment->construct<map_pointer_type>("elements ptr")(
            segment->construct<map_type>("elements")(std::less<IdClass>(), alloc_inst),      //object to own
            void_allocator_type(segment_manager),  //allocator
            map_deleter_type(segment_manager)         //deleter
            );
```

And then in the Child process to only get a copy of this pointer

```
map_pointer_type elements = *segment->find<map_pointer_type>("elements ptr").first;
```

Answer (score 3):

- **Q:** *Am I initializing the `boost::interprocess::shared_ptr` in a wrong way?*

You're doing it right. You don't need the segment in a shared pointer though. Just make sure the segment outlives any interprocess shared_ptrs (or, for that matter any references into the shared memory segment).

- **Q:**  *Am I missing completely the semantics of this pointer --> is it used only to manage shared-memory objects lifecycle only within one process and not across processes?*

No.

- **Q:** *How to have a `shared_ptr` whose `use_count` is shared across processes?*

Docs: [`make_managed_shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/make_managed_s_idp34227264.html):

> *Returns an instance of a shared pointer constructed with the default allocator and deleter from a pointer of type T that has been allocated in the passed managed segment*.

The [other page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.shared_ptr) explicitly mentions (**emphasis** mine):

> Since the **reference count and other auxiliary data needed by shared_ptr must be created also in the managed segment**, and the deleter has to delete the object from the segment, the user must specify an allocator object and a deleter object when constructing a non-empty instance of shared_ptr

Comment: Needless to say (?) I think your problem is elsewhere. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505817/shared-lifecycle-cross-processes-with-boostinterprocessshared-ptr/30506363#comment49087745_30505817) on the question.

Comment: Given how I initialized the shared pointer, is the auxiliary data going to be in the managed segment?

Comment: **Y.E.S.** I can't spell it out more.

Comment: @sehe What exactly do you mean by : "You don't need the segment in a shared pointer though"

Comment: @Vassilis You don't need to share ownership to the segment itself.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that if I try to create any object in the Parent process in the shared memory after the Child process is dead, I get an assert error:

```
assertion "hdr->m_value_alignment == algn" failed: 
file "/usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/segment_manager_helper.hpp", line 181, 
function: static boost::interprocess::detail::block_header* boost::interprocess::detail::block_header::block_header_from_value(const void*, size_t, size_t)
```

So now I suspect that it's the way I'm spawning the child process from the parent process.

```
  //Launch child process
  std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
  std::cout << "Child about to be born" <<  std::endl;

  if(0 != std::system(s.c_str())){
     std::cout << "(Parent): Child failed!" << std::endl;
     return 1;
  }
```